# C# Switch If condition to expand the switch cases

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I have some data which need to converted, for that I need a switch condition with more than 50 cases, I need the same cases 3 times but in the third time I need the 50 cases and some more and I don't want to write the same code twice. Maybe there is a possibility to do something like this.

```
switch (example)
{
    case "1":
        //do something
    case "2":
        //do something
    case "50":
        //do something
    //now maybe something like this
    if (condition == true)
    {
        case "1":
            //do something else than above at case "1", and so on 
            //now its i little bit illogical, but i neet to do the first 50 cases and then
            //use the cases 1 to 50 again but with other actions 
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear, what are you looking for?

Comment: So, in `case "50"` you want to check `case "51"` and so on too ?

Comment: You can try the goto statement, though not recommended

Comment: What do your actions for 1-50 (condition == false) and 1-50 with the condition true look like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting from C# 7 you can combine [the `case` statement with `when` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) and use it to simplify your code a little bit

```cs
switch (example)
{
    case "1":
        //do something
    case "2":
        //do something
    case "50":
        //do something
    //now maybe something like this
    case "51" when condition == true:
        //do something, and so on  
    default:
        break;   
}
```

> Starting with C# 7.0, because `case` statements need not be mutually
>   exclusive, you can add a `when` clause to specify an additional
>   condition that must be satisfied for the `case` statement to evaluate to
>   true. The `when` clause can be any expression that returns a `Boolean`
>   value.

Comment: It is good, but in that more cases which i need, some cases need twice like case "0": and if i do this with the when clause it don´t work.

Comment: @Luuke It isn't fully clear, what do you mean by twice here. Please, update your question with these details. To transfer control between `case` statements you can use [`goto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) statement

Comment: @Luuke if you need to use the cases again with different actions, it looks like a writing a new cases and putting them in a separate method. Or put all actions under the same `case` and control with `when` clause. Can you share the example of actions? Why do you need to repeat the same cases with different actions?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are looking for a way not to repeat `if (condition == true)`.  Aside from the new `when` clause in C#7, you could also take a different approach with two `switch` statements:

```
if (!condition)
{
    switch (example)
    {
        case "1":
            //do something
        case "2":
            //do something
        case "50":
            //do something
    }
} else {
    switch (example)
    {
        case "51:
            //do something, and so on 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an always match case with a `with` of the condition.

```
switch (example)
{
    case "1":
    case example when condition == true:
        //do something
    case "2":
        //do something
    case "50":
        //do something
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.